# ODBC with Ruby Connection String

Tags: database, ruby

I'm trying to access an Access database from Ruby.

```
dbh = DBI.connect('DBI:ODBC:test','','')
```

works, but

```
 dbh = DBI.connect("DBI:ODBC:driver=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb);dbq=H:/test.accdb")
```

doesn't.

I don't want to setup the Access Driver on every single machine.

Why isn't the second line working?

The ODBC-driver says something like the database wasn't recognized by my program.

Comment: this really is better suited for SO

Comment: voted to close and migrate to SO.

Answer (score 0):

I never worked with the new `accdb`-format, but I connected successful to `mdb`-files via the [Jet-engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Jet_Database_Engine) and sequel..

You may test my code example if it works with your accdb-file:

```
require 'sequel'

Dir['*.mdb'].each{|mdb|
      print "Check #{mdb}"
      @db = Sequel.ado(:conn_string=>"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=#{mdb}")
      begin
        @db.test_connection 
        puts " ok"
      rescue Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError
        puts " error"
      end
}
```

If you prefer a winole-variant you may check [How do I query a MS Access database table, and export the information to Excel using Ruby and win32ole?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573936/how-do-i-query-a-ms-access-database-table-and-export-the-information-to-excel-u)

http://rubyonwindows.blogspot.de/2007/06/using-ruby-ado-to-work-with-ms-access.html

Answer (score 0):

There is another Access-ODBC driver with *.mdb **and** *.accdb in its name. You have to select this one.

Comment: accdb is still Access although it's a much more recent format that brings with it new capabilities. As such you'll need to connect to these databases using a different driver: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255