# ODBC connection with MS Access in Ruby (.accdb)

Tags: ruby, database, ms-access, odbc, connection-string

I have a .accdb file (from Microsoft Access) that would connect to ODBC database and read data in my Ruby file (C:/Documents/foo.rb)

[In case this information is necessary, I'm using Windows 10 and MS Access 2010 and would like to connect to .accdb file]

From [this website: Connection Strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2010/), I found this bit of code but it's not in Ruby:

```
Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=C:\mydatabase.accdb;
Uid=Admin;Pwd=;
```

And from [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120225/ruby-and-accdb-ms-access), someone provides excellent code in Ruby but it's using the ACE engine instead of ODBC:

```
require 'win32ole'
connection = WIN32OLE.new('ADODB.Connection')
connection.Open('Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
                 Data Source=c:\path\filename.accdb')
```

This [Stackflowquestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146134/odbc-with-ruby-connection-string) uses the JET engine (also in Ruby):

```
require 'sequel'

Dir['*.mdb'].each{|mdb|
    print "Check #{mdb}"
    @db = Sequel.ado(:conn_string=>"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=#{mdb}")
    begin
        @db.test_connection 
        puts " ok"
    rescue Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError
        puts " error"
    end
}
```

I feel like I'm very close to finding the connection string but I've looked online and couldn't improve what I already have. I would very much appreciate a connection in Ruby that connects .accdb files in ODBC database.

Comment: (Also, apology in advance if this is a very rudimentary question - I have just started learning Ruby)

Comment: While it appears you have already asked this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51475118/connecting-ruby-and-ms-access-using-odbc (Maybe delete one of them). [`rdbi-driver-odbc`](https://github.com/RDBI/rdbi-driver-odbc) can make ODBC connections to access using a dsn

Comment: ahh my apologies - I improved the question on this post and simply forgot to delete my previous post. Thank you!